# Python: solving unicode hell with unidecode

Tags: python, unicode

I have been working on ways to flatten text into ascii. So **ā** -> **a** and **ñ** -> **n**, etc.

`unidecode` has been fantastic for this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode
print(unidecode(u"ā, ī, ū, ś, ñ"))
print(unidecode(u"Estado de São Paulo"))
```

Produces:

```
a, i, u, s, n
Estado de Sao Paulo
```

However, I can't duplicate this result with data from an input file.

Content of test.txt file:

```
ā, ī, ū, ś, ñ
Estado de São Paulo
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode
with open("test.txt", 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        print unidecode(line.strip())
```

Produces:

```
A, A<<, A<<, A, A+-
Estado de SAPSo Paulo
```

And:

> RuntimeWarning: Argument  is not an unicode object.
>   Passing an encoded string will likely have unexpected results.

**Question**: How can I read these lines in as unicode so that I can pass them to `unidecode`?

Comment: Why is this "Unicode hell"? Those are perfectly good accented characters. Hell would be if they were mutilated beyond repair (which some may argue that your solution actually does).

Comment: I agree. These are tip-top characters, and I feel very guilty for steamrolling them, but that is what I did. Good news is that I'll have time to think about it in ascii purgatory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)

```
with codecs.open("test.txt", 'r', 'utf-8') as inf:
```

Edit: The above was for Python 2.x.  For Python 3 you don't need to use `codecs`, the encoding parameter has been added to regular `open`.

```
with open("test.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inf:
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('test.txt', encoding='whicheveronethefilewasencodedwith') as f:
    ...
```

The [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html) module provides a function to open files with automatic Unicode encoding/decoding, among other things.

Comment: Thanks. Both answers were perfect, went with Mark since he was first.